# Can't access to phpmyadmin in XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

I tried to access phpmyadmin page on XAMPP control panel. access is denied with message says access denied due to incorrect configuration.

I changed port setting to Apache and mySQL as default setting was conflicting with other application. below picture is my port setting. I changed port setting in Apache (httpd.conf), Apache (httpd-ssl.conf), my.ini .

[image]

I've tried to search existing Q&As, but failed to find out proper solution to my case. what I could assume is that changing port setting affected accessibility to phpmyadmin.

is there anything to should checking up to access phpmyadmin properly?